# Activerecord query to get collection based on associated attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following association:

```
business belongs_to :loan

business has_many :property_addresses, class_name: 'Address::Property', as: :addressable

Address::Property has a column called as_collateral which holds a boolean.
```

From my Loan model, I want to be create a scope that returns loans with a property_address that has as_collateral as true. (i.e. `Loan.with_collateral`)

I tried several versions of the following query (different pluralization) but keep getting an error:

```
 Loan.joins(:business => :property_addresses).where('businesses.property_addresses.as_collateral': true).first

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'businesses.property_addresses.as_collateral'
```

Comment: Does this work? `Loan.joins(:business => :property_addresses).where('property_addresses.as_collateral': true).first`

Comment: @Iceman Nope, i still get the error ` Unknown column 'property_addresses.as_collateral‌​`, but the answer below works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `merge` method, It's useful when you need to intersect queries. Read more [in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge)

```
Loan.joins(business: :property_addresses)
  .merge(PropertyAddress.where(as_collateral: true))
```

The resultant SQL query will be

```
SELECT `loans`.* FROM `loans`
INNER JOIN `businesses`
    ON `businesses`.`id` = `loans`.`business_id`
INNER JOIN `property_addresses`
    ON `property_addresses`.`business_id` = `businesses`.`id`
WHERE `property_addresses`.`as_collateral` = 1
```